# jquery modal dialogue not popping up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a pop up div that appears while my app is completing a task.  When the ajax task is complete, I'd like to remove the pop up. 
I've been reviewing http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal and have tried to implement a similar solution.  But I'm unable to get my div to pop up.  Here's my code to create the div:

```
<div id="progress-indicator">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/wip.gif" /> Please Wait...
</div>
```

then later on the page, I have some javascript to hide the div until someone clicks on a button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#progress-indicator').hide();
});


$('#saveData').live('click', function()  {
//$('#progress-indicator').show();
    $( "#progress-indicator" ).dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
});
});
```

Unfortunately, don't get a pop up when the save button is clicked.  if you could tell me where I've gone wrong, i'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Edit:
I know that the button click event is fired because before attempting to create a pop up div, I had a line to just make the div visible within the existing page.  And that works.  So for example, the following code works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#progress-indicator').hide();
});

$('#save').live('click', function()  {
$('#progress-indicator').show();
});
```

This code works fine except for the fact that I want a pop up that's centered on the page.

Edit 2: 
By the way guys, i also checked the web developer console in firefox and there are no error messages being generated.  in case that helps...
Also, I am including both jquery and jquery-ui:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the callback fires? I thought that .live() is now deprecated. Have you tried .on() ?

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+. It is better to use `.on()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: 1. Yes you need to hide the div, or else it will just be sitting there on your page when it loads.  But I would do with css, rather than javascript in document ready.  If you do it on document ready, you may see the div briefly before it hides.

Comment: @d4rklit3 - i edited my post to include the information you're looking for.

Comment: @MBJ - Thanks.  I changed my code to use the .on instead.

Comment: Can you use Firebug or the Chrome inspector to see if there is a javascript error when the call to dialog() is made?  And, forgive me if this sounds insulting, but double-check that you have both jquery AND jquery UI included on your page, they are different things.

Comment: @jfrank, see my updated post.  And, no, not insulted.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: OK, I would next separate out the showing of the dialog from the binding of the click function, so there are fewer moving parts.  What happens if you just make the call to .dialog() in your document ready, instead of inside the click handler?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16509/discussion-between-dot-and-jfrank)

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your document ready too soon. The binding of the click with live or on should be within the document ready. Now your document ready ends right after the first hide. This way there's a good chance the dialog function isn't loaded yet when the click event is binded.

Comment: can you give me a little more background information / explanation?

Comment: See my answer you want to wait with binding untill the dialog function is loaded.

Comment: I modified the document ready so that it encompassed all the jquery stuff.  Same behavior.  No pop up. I checked the web developer console in Firefox, and no errors either.

Answer (score 0):

This will pop up dialog box

```
<div id="progress-indicator" style="display:none;">
 <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/wip.gif" /> Please Wait...
</div>

(function ($) {
 $('#saveData').click(function()  {
 $( "#progress-indicator" ).dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I just tried adding that to my document. ready but it didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: are you able to see dialog box ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the dialog before the click() event. and within the click, you need to call the open().

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#progress-indicator" ).dialog({
    height: 140,
    modal: true
    });
$('#progress-indicator').hide();

$('#save').click( function()  {
$('#progress-indicator').dialog('open');   
});
});
```